# "Above and beyond" security for data in transit between two corporate servers

Tags: rest, security, encryption, https, network-security

I'm building an enterprise-level API to automatically send and receive private data between two corporate servers. The data will be sent in daily batches to send large amounts of private data to a receiving server in another data center. I'm coding both the API on the receiving server and the automated task on the sending server to automatically connect to the API server and send the daily data.

Data will be transmitted via an HTTPS endpoint. An API key (using a random 30 character string) is required to authenticate the API between the sending server and receiving server.

I'm being asked to go above and beyond to ensure the security of the data while in transit between the two servers. A few things I'm currently considering:

1. Is coding an additional private/public key pair exchange between the servers for authentication needed if we already use HTTPS + API key? I don't think a private/public key pair really provides additional authentication security -- as long as the API key is stored securely (and other precautions such as changing the API key on a monthly basis) coding a private/public key pair exchange doesn't seem to offer any additional security?
2. Is it worth it to encrypt the data in the code on the sending server, to be decrypted by the receiving server? We're using an HTTPS connection which already encrypts the data, and honestly a second level of encryption seems like overkill and useless (not to mention whether our programming team can even provide better encryption security than SSL which is already best practice).
3. Protection against other types of attacks. For example to protect against a man-in-the-middle replay attack we require a unique session key be sent along with the data. The session key is only accepted once by the receiving server and so a replay attack will be rejected. However this is only to ensure data integrity on the receiving server by making sure the same request can't be sent twice.

I'm looking for other suggestions that would be considered enterprise-level best practice to protect the API authentication process, security of the data while in transit, or protection against other types of attacks for this scenario. Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use HTTPS with client certificate (can be self-signed). Just make sure the server only accepts this one client certificate. On client side you can implement CA (or leaf) certificate pinning just to make sure you are talking to the correct server.

Comment: There are many security measures on multiple levels (SOAP+WS-Security, mutual SSL,..) but at the end, what are the requirements? What is the thread model? This forum encourages to ask specific question in a specific context. At the end - if all requirements (fn, non-fn) and policies are covered, then a good enough solution may be good enough